# ping problem from a single host

Tags: windows-server-2003, tcpip, windows

I've a host 10.10.10.1 which i can ping from other machine but ping was sudden stopped from nms machine where the above IP is being monitored 24/7. 
any help?

It has being to work so now i'm unable to check in more details. If issue persist. I'll let you know with the findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might run an `ARP -a` command to see if the MAC address is the same. I had an issue where I rebooted a workstaiton and I could keep pinging it from 1 server, but not from another server while it rebooted. Found that someone had setup a managed switch with the same IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Your going to need to try and do some more diagnosis before we can offer a solution to this. If you run a ping command form the command line on your NMS machine, what do you get back. If you run a tracert from that machine, how far along the chain does it get?

Do you have a firewall on either of those machines, could there be a rule in place to block pings from either machine?